# How to assign axes from one figure to axes from another figure?

Tags: python, function, matplotlib, figure, axes

everybody!

I want to assign axes from one figure to axes from another figure, can you tell me how to do this?

Actually, I've two functions, both of which return axes. I want to create a new figure with two axes that will represent exactly the two that I get from the functions. I tried to manipulate with attributs, but I failed:(

So this is example of my code:

```
def draw(data, markup_data, size = 7):

    ...

    _, ax2 = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 7))
    ax2.scatter(x, y, s=size, c=data, linewidths=0, alpha=0.9)
    ax2.grid(False)
    return ax2
```

main:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(10,5))

axes[0] = draw(data_1)
axes[1] = draw(data_2)

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Axes can't be moved to another figure.  The recommended approach is to supply the `ax` as a parameter to `draw(....., ax=...)`.

The code structure could be as follows:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def draw(data, size=7, ax=None):
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()  # use current axis if none is given
    ax.scatter(data['x'], data['y'], s=size, c=data['c'], linewidths=0, alpha=0.9)
    ax.grid(False)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 5))
draw(data_1, ax=axes[0])
draw(data_2, ax=axes[1])
fig.show()
```

Often, the parameters to `scatter` are also provided. Python supports such extra keywords via `**kwargs` and converts them to a dictionary. For parameters to `scatter` that are not provided by the user, the `draw` function then can set its own defaults. Here is a more elaborate example:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def draw(data, size=7, ax=None, **kwargs):
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()  # use current axis if none is given
    print(kwargs)
    if 's' not in kwargs:
        kwargs['s'] = 7
    if 'linewidths' not in kwargs:
        kwargs['linewidths'] = 0
    if 'alpha' not in kwargs:
        kwargs['alpha'] = 0.9
    print(kwargs)
    ax.scatter(data['x'], data['y'], c=data['c'], **kwargs)
    ax.grid(False)

data_1 = {'x': np.random.rand(800), 'y': np.random.rand(800), 'c': np.random.rand(800)}
data_2 = {'x': np.random.rand(200), 'y': np.random.rand(200), 'c': np.random.rand(200)}

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 5))
draw(data_1, ax=axes[0])
draw(data_2, ax=axes[1], linewidths=1, edgecolor='gold', s=20)
fig.show()
```

[image: example plot]